# Change OpenSSL library internal name with 'chatr' command on HPIA

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I need to change the internal name of libcrypto.so.0.9.8 shared library to libcrypto.so for a specific purpose. I am unable to do so with the chatr command which only displays the internal name.

There is a restriction that I am unable to re compile the shared library with +h option giving the internal name, which was my initial idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LD_PRELOAD environment variable. It allows you to interpose libraries.

Basically you setup a symlink, in a directory you control, named  libcrypto.so.0.9.8, which points to the library you want to use,  (I guess): /lib/libcrypto.so.  Aim LD_PRELOAD at the symlink.

LD_PRELOAD will NOT work with setuid programs in HPUX.

You did carefully verify that all of the entry points you use in your code are in  libcrypto.so?

Since I have no real idea what is going on this may not be an ideal solution.  It is a best guess.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even though you have the symlink the loader's only focus is on the internal name. LD_PRELOAD is good option although it would not work out in this case. In the end I recompiled OpenSSL removing the +h option in Makefile.shared for hpux.